# Where is test result stored in MTM 2010?

Tags: microsoft-test-manager

I am trying to provide a copy of the test result recorded using MTM 2010 to client, do you know where to grab the result?

Thanks.

Comment: When you say "Test Result", what part of MTM are you referring to? There are quite a few ways to view results, can you show a screen shot of the data you want to export?

Comment: Test result refers to the video recorded during test execution. in MTM, result is recorded in run test component. I would like to export the video instead of viewing it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The test run and its attachments are stored on the TFS server and available via the  TFS SDK. See the [TestManagementService apis](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd998375.aspx) where ITestRun.Attachments would contain all test run associated attachments

```
var testsvc = tfs.GetService<TestManagementService>()
IEnumerable<ITestRun> testRun = testsvc.GetTeamProject("myteamprojectname").TestRuns; // you can use the query/find
```

Answer (score 1):

I follow either of below mentioned two ways to analyze my test runs :

1. Run following command from "Run":
   start mtm://[tfsserver:portnumber/tfs/collectionname]/p:[teamproject]/testing/testrun/open?id=
2. downloading results file (.trx) to my local system:
   tcm run /export /id:id /resultsfile:[my_local_path] /collection:CollectionURL /teamproject:project [/login:username,[password]] [/attachment:attachmentname]